# Show that $5\cdot10^n+10^{n-1}+3$ is divisible by 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove by induction the following:

> $5*10^n+10^{n-1}+3$ is divisible by 9

Base case: $n=1$ $5*10+10^{1-1}+3=5*10+10^0+3=50+1+3=54$

$9|54=6$

Inductive Hypothesis: If $k$ is a natural number such that $9|5*10^k+10^{k-1} +3$

Inductive step:
Show that $S_k$ is true $\Rightarrow$ $S_{k+1}$ is true

$S_{k+1}$: $9|5*10^{k+1}+10^{k} +3$

$9|10(5*10^{k+1}+10^{k} +3)$

$9|5*10^{k+2}+10^{k+1} +10*3$

$9|5*(10^{k+1}*10^1)+(10^{k}*10^1) +(9+1)*3$

$9|5*(10^{k+1}*(9+1))+(10^{k}*10*(9+1)) +(9+1)*3$

$9|5(9*10^{k+1}+10^{k+1})+9*10^k+10^k+((9*3)+(1*3))$

This is were I am stuck for the last day try to figure out what move next would speed up the inductive proof as I have a feeling it can be finished up. Anyone help me see what I am unable to find.

Comment: Do you have to do induction.  Note the number when written out will be 5100000......00003.  Does that give you a hint?  Something about determining if a number is divisible by 9?

Comment: Btw this can be solved by congruences quite elegantly $5\cdot 10^n+10^{n-1}+3 \equiv 5\cdot  1^n+1^{n-1}+3 = 9 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to show this kind of an equality, is to show that $S_{k-1} - S_k$ is divisible by $9$.

\begin{split} S_{k+1} - S_k & = (5 \times 10^{k+1} + 10^{k} + 3) -  (5 \times 10^k + 10^{k-1} + 3)\\ & = 5(10^{k+1}-10^k) + (10^k-10^{k-1}) \\ & = 5\times 9 \times 10^k + 9 \times 10^{k-1} \\ & = 9 \times (5 \times 10^k + 10^{k-1})  \end{split}

Hence, $S_{k+1} = S_k + 9 \times (5 \times 10^k + 10^{k-1})$. Since $9|S_k$ and $9|9 \times (5 \times 10^k + 10^{k-1})$, it is clear that $9|S_{k+1}$. Hence, the induction is complete.

It is also nice to note that the pattern of numbers produced by $S_k$ go like $54$,$513$,$5103$,$51003$ etc. all of which have sum of digits the same i.e. $9$, so all are divisible by $9$ (this needn't be proved inductively at all)

Comment: The issue is the way it must be solved is by manipulating similar to what I did and like that of one the posters below. The professor does not enjoy the S_{k+1}-S_k he calls it the most obvious way of solving. But thanks I will use it as a backup way going forward.

Comment: @JamesMcNoir I see. My apologies, but even if this is one of the obvious ways of solving, it is easily the most powerful.

Comment: I agree, it was what I was use to. The poster below this shows a way of getting the end the way I need. However, the IH is not fully correct. Which I have pointed out to him.

Comment: The IH seems correct to me. On the other hand, I don't understand what you meant when you said that the IH is $10^k+10^k-1$, down below in the other post. The IH you wrote in the question above doesn't match with this either.

Comment: $$9|5\times10^k+10^{k-1}+3$$ however in once he take care of 27, he states that he is back to the IH but they are not.

Comment: He is, right? He has increased the index to $k+1$, so the equation has now become:$$ 9 | 5 \times 10^{k+1} + 10^k + 3$$. The index has increased by $1$, right? This was what was supposed to happen in the induction.

Comment: After second look he definitely has. That answers my question. I had to relook and forgot that I'm suppose to get the $k+1$

Comment: @JamesMcNoir  Great to see your problem was cleared. $+1$ for your question, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Induction hypothesis:
$$9|5\times10^k+10^{k-1}+3$$
Thus,
$$9|10(5\times10^k+10^{k-1}+3)$$
$$9|5\times10^{k+1}+10^k+30$$
$$9|5\times10^{k+1}+10^k+3+27$$
But $9|27$. Hence,
$$9|5\times10^{k+1}+10^k+3$$
which is what had to be shown.

Comment: But our IH is $10^k+10^k-1$, I need to show the way I manipulated the other 2 terms like you did with 3 + 27 .

Comment: If a|b then a|10b (or any kb).  I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if for some $n \geq 1$ the proposition is true then $5\cdot 10^{n} + 10^{n-1} + 3 = 9k$ for some $k$; hence
$$
5\cdot 10^{n+1} + 10^{n} + 3 = 90k - 27.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$5\cdot10^{n+1}+10^{n} +3=10\cdot5\cdot10^{n}+10\cdot10^{n-1}+30-27=$$
$$=10(5\cdot10^{n}+10^{n-1} +3)-3\cdot9$$

Answer (score 0):

An integer is divisible by $3^k$ if and only if the sum of the digits is divisible by $3^k$. In this case, note the sum of the digits is always $9$!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for induction, the answer is immediate with modular arithmetic!
$$ 5\cdot10^n+10^{n-1}+3\equiv 5\cdot1^n+1^{n-1}+3=5+4=9\equiv0\pmod{9}$$